# How to detect tabular data in raw bytes

Tags: algorithm

There are a number of incoming data blocks containing raw bytes with unknown structure, and block size is known in advance. There is a need to detect whether a block contains some tabular data structure or not. In other words, there is a need to know are the raw bytes formed as tabular data  or not. Is there any known approach to detect it? Maybe applying autocorrelation function helps or something else?

Simple example:

```
0000:|0A 0B 01 02 03|0A 0B 04 05 06|0A 0B 07 08 09|0A 
0010: 0B 0A 0B 0C|0A 0B 0D 0E 0F|0A 0B 10 11 12|0A 0B 
0020: 13 14 15|0A 0B 16 17 18|0A 0B 19 1A 1B|0A 0B 1C
...
```

In this example, there is the incoming binary data block containing some 5-byte records starting with the obvious marker - 0x0b0a. In case the marker is known in advance, records can be easily extracted from the data block. However markers are not known, and records, if any, can have different formats and sizes.

I'm trying to solve the problem in general, so it doesn't matter if a block matches any particular data format, e.g. csv, or a custom format. What I have already found is the [one page article](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=1281497) with the described idea. The idea works in general, but not for all data. (At least it doesn't work for data with variable record length.) So now I'm wondering if there are implemented approaches, however I don’t need particular implementation. The question is more about existing solutions and sharing experience if any.

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: @Fogmeister I’m using C/C++, but I don’t need particular implementation. The question is more about existing solutions and sharing experience if any.

Comment: Probably worth putting that somewhere in the question or tags. Also, "tabular data" is fairly vague also. Do you mean like a csv format? Or tsv? Or something else?

Comment: @Fogmeister I extended the question with the example.